# How to create a completely empty (or close to it) response from asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, httpresponse, httpmodule

I created an HttpModule to restrict access from certain IPs. I want to use as little bandwidth as possible and not return the default IIS 404 page. I would rather return no content at all.

```
    private static void OnBeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpApplication app = sender as HttpApplication;
        app.Response.StatusCode = 404;
        app.Context.Response.Clear();
        app.Context.Response.End();
    }
```

Changing the status code to 200 works and create 0 bytes of content in the response but now I'm curious as to how to do it no matter the statuscode.

Comment: Is there a problem with what you have?

Comment: @JamesCurran Yes. It returns the default IIS 404 page

Answer (score 0):

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Error/Index.html">
    <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Error/404Error.html" />
</customErrors>
```

Add this to your web.config. And of course, adjust urls based on your project.